# Replace Windows 10 with Lubuntu

Tags: usb, lubuntu, windows-10

Im on a HP Mini 110-3800 with a Intel Atom CPU N455 (1.66 Ghz) and 1 GB RAM.

Since both Windows 7 Starter as well as the upgraded Windows 10 are both too slow for this netbook, I want to replace Windows 10 with Lubuntu.

I don't have a CD-Drive, so I used UNetbootin to get the Lubuntu 15.04-desktop-i386 on an USB-Stick. I changed the Boot-Priority in the Windows BIOS and still Windows boots up without any Ubuntu Setup.

Can you please tell me what to do? I just want to get rid of Windows (10)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you used UNetbootin to make a bootable Lubuntu USB flash drive in Windows 10, but UNetbootin is not supported by Windows 10. The official instructions at www.ubuntu.com for creating a bootable USB stick to install (L)ubuntu are at this link: [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). The program used in the official instructions at www.ubuntu.com is [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), which is supported by Windows 10.

There are also official instructions for creating a bootable USB stick to install Ubuntu on Ubuntu at: [How to create a bootable USB stick
on Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

Comment: And, as obvious as it may seem, you can always check if your bootable usb stick is viable or not by using it on another computer...